# Budget abrasive for vibration polishing

Tags: materials, polishing

We're making a vibration polisher for polishing laser-cut aluminum and steel parts, and we're looking for the abrasive medium to fill it with. We need about 30 liters of it - and the one we found (for jewelry use) was prohibitively expensive in the required amounts. We tried with several gravel kinds and the results were underwhelming.

What material, that would be easy to obtain and inexpensive is a common choice for a vibration polisher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever is suitable from a powder to steel balls, sand to shells. This link gives you some info : http://www.kramerindustriesonline.com/tumbling-media.htm

Answer (score 1):

try something called sharp plaster sand. this is sold in building supply stores and is basically a high grade of beach sand with very little dirt or silt in it, and is sold in bags. it is cheap.